# Safely migrating tables and columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-migration

We're looking to change the names of a large number of tables in our database. Is there a safe way to remain backwards compatible when we do this?

For example, if our code references table A, and we want to rename table A to table B, can we alias the table A commands so that they are sent to table B? That way we can migrate the database first, then we can migrate the application over time to point to the new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it could be done with Views, for example after doing this:

```
CREATE VIEW A AS SELECT * FROM B;
```

anything querying A, would actually get the data from real table B.
However their behavior is not the same as tables, so it may not be suitable, first check:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html

Comment: Ah based on my description this would actually work, but we will be viewing several tables at once joined together and it looks like view inserts and updates are only available for a single table. It doesn't look like this is possible for us.